# How do I make a voice call from my Java app? How do I make this program work?

Tags: java, phone-call, voice

I am trying to make a call to a number, or any random voice service because it does not have to be functional as this is a school project. Here is the code for my jframe.

What I want to do is, when I click the call icon, it calls the number or a voice program.

```
public class Counselling extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Counselling frame = new Counselling();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Counselling() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 510, 450);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("");
        Image images = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/call.png")).getImage();
        btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(images));
        btnNewButton.setBounds(106, 92, 268, 133);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);


        JButton button = new JButton("");
        button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Image images2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/msg.png")).getImage();
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(images2));
        button.setBounds(106, 241, 268, 125);
        contentPane.add(button);



        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("");
        Image images1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/oc.png")).getImage();
        lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(images1));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(38, 16, 435, 60);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this question and code is the equivalent of creating a "Hello World" program and asking it to use it to launch nuclear missiles. You've not shown that you've done any research on the parts of the program that really matter yet.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio is the most common service out there and is extremely affordable. If you are using Maven, install by adding it to your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>twilio-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is some example code on how you would place a phone call:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Account;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Call;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.CallFactory;

public class MakeCall {

    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "AC123";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "456bef";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {

        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID,     AUTH_TOKEN);
        Account mainAccount = client.getAccount();
        CallFactory callFactory = mainAccount.getCallFactory();
        Map<String, String> callParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        callParams.put("To", "5105551212"); // Replace with your phone number
        callParams.put("From", "(510) 555-1212"); // Replace with a Twilio number
        callParams.put("Url", "http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/");
        // Make the call
        Call call = callFactory.create(callParams);
        // Print the call SID (a 32 digit hex like CA123..)
        System.out.println(call.getSid());
    }
}
```

Check out the Twilio install guide for java for more information:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install